# Convergent sequence in Lp has a subsequence bounded by another Lp function

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

For $E$ a measurable set and $1\leq p<\infty $, assume $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(E)$. Show that there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ and a function $g\in L^p(E)$ such that $|f_{n_k}|\leq g$ almost everywhere on $E$ for all $k$.

By convergence in $L^p(E)$, I mean that $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$. I know that a convergent sequence in $L^p$ has a subsequence that converges pointwise a.e. to $f$ on $E$. Since $f\in L^p(E)$, it must be finite almost everywhere. I would like to define $g$ to be the pointwise supremum of the $f_{n_k}$, but there is no guarantee that this supremum is finite almost everywhere. How can I construct $g$ to bound this subsequence above pointwise?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$, for every $k\in \Bbb N$, there exists $n_k\in \Bbb N$, such that $\|f_{n_k}-f\|_p\le \frac{1}{2^k}$. Let 
$$g:=|f|+\sum_{k=1}^\infty |f_{n_k}-f|.$$
By definition, $g$ is measurable, and $g\ge |f|+|f_{n_k}-f|\ge|f_{n_k}|$ for every $k\in \Bbb N$ . Moreover, by Minkowski's inequality, 
$$\|g\|_p\le \|f\|_p+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|f_{n_k}-f\|_p\le \|f\|_p+1.$$

Comment: This is a very good solution. I learned a lot from it.

Comment: @user32240: I am glad to hear that my answer is helpful to you. :)

Comment: I thought about this for a few minutes, and was thinking about using $\inf\sup |f_{n}|$. But this is just $|f|$ and I could not find a subsequence that would work. I think your solution is better.

Comment: @user104254 I think there is a mistake in the answer, or maybe I can not understand something. My point is that $g$ by definition is the pointwise limit of the series $|f(x)|+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{|f_{n_k}-f|}$. But this is not necessarily the $L_p$ limit of the series. Therefore when you apply Minkowski's inequality, it is actually applied to the $L_p$ limit of the series, call it $w$. So you have $\|w\|_p\leq \|f\|_p+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{\|f_{n_k}-f\|_p}\leq \|f\|_p+1$

Comment: So how can we see that indeed $g\in L_p$ ?

Comment: Aha, I justified this: I showed (maybe it is obvious) that $\|g\|_p=\|w\|_p\leq \infty$ by using the monotone convergence theorem.