# Continuity of a function between $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Consider $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that

$$ \psi(t) \leq M \vert t \vert, \forall t\in \mathbb{R} \label{a}\tag{1}$$

for some $M>0$. Define $F: L^p(X) \rightarrow L^p(X)$ by $F(f)= \psi \circ f$ (well defined by (\ref{a})). If $F$ continuous?.

If $\psi$ is linear I prove that $F$ is bounded and linear so continuous. But, in the case $\psi$ is not linear I can't prove. Any hint? Or an example where F is not continuous. Thanks!

Comment: $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is just an arbitrary measure space?

Comment: It is relatively easy to see that $F$ preserves convergence in measure (or a.e. convergence along subsequences, if you are not familiar with convergence in measure). Then you can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @maowao this doesn't really make much sense to me

Comment: @JustDroppedIn See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that whenever $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that $F(f_{n_k})\to F(f)$ in $L^p$.

If $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e. We can additionally assume that there exists $g\in L^p$ such that $|f_{n_k}|\leq g$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711726/convergent-sequence-in-lp-has-a-subsequence-bounded-by-another-lp-function)). Since $\psi$ is continuous, we also have $F(f_{n_k})\to F(f)$ a.e. Moreover, the assumption on $\psi$ implies $|F(f_{n_k})|\leq M|f_{n_k}|\leq M g$ a.e. Thus $F(f_{n_k})\to F(f)$ in $L^p$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: If the first sentence is not clear, I can expand on that.

Comment: So does $F(f_n)\to F(f)$ in $L^p$?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Yes. This argument applies to every subsequence of $(F(f_n))$. And if every subsequence has a subsequence converging to the same limit, then the original sequence converges to that limit (in any topological space).

Comment: But, you only find a subsequence $F(f_{n_k})$ such that converge to $F(f)$. Not for all subsequence of $F(f_n)$

Comment: You can apply my argument to any subsequence of $(f_n)$. And you don't have to show that all subsequences converge, just that every subsequence has a converging subsequence with the correct limit.

Comment: Thanks, I understand